# Fit with conditional statement returning NaN

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following dataset

```
4456.5  140.5   1
4371.4  142.1   1
4389.8  150.5   1
4716.9  306.3   4
7505.4  1117.6  4
13517.3 2298.2  2
13961.3 2358.3  2
13994.7 2444.3  2
```

and I want to fit only the points with a specific value in the third column.
With `plot` I'd use the conditional `using 1:($3==1?$2:NaN)` but

```
LS(x) = a*x**2 + b*x + c
a=0.00001; b1=0.; c=0. 
fit LS(x) IFN u 1:($3==1?$2:NaN) via a,b,c
```

doesn't work because the `NaN` values are fitted as well and I get

```
> print a1,b1,c1
NaN NaN 0.0001
```

Is there a way to fit a conditional subset without having to re-write the input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the third column in the `using` statement to set a very large variance for the points you want to ignore:

```
reset
IFN='test.txt'
LS(x) = a*x**2 + b*x + c
a=-0.00001; b=0.5; c=-2000 
fit LS(x) IFN u 1:2:($3==1? 10000 : 1) via a,b,c
plot LS(x), IFN
```

Alternatively, you can use `awk` to filter the input file on-the-fly:

```
fit LS(x) "< awk '($3 != 1)' ".IFN u 1:2 via a,b,c
```

Comment: That's it, thanks for the answer! I remember using this trick before.
Using `awk` is not a possibility for me (Windows platform with a strict software policy, corporate environment).